# Checkbox is unchecked but the content of a checked checkbox is showing up

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Just like the title says.
Here is my code:

```
$('#somediv').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('.leaflet-marker-pane').show(1);
    }
    else {
        $('.leaflet-marker-pane').hide(1);
    }       
});
```

```html
<input style="float: left;" type="checkbox" id="somediv" name="somediv">
```

This happens when the browser is refreshed. The content should not show up, because the checkbox is unchecked, but it is showing up.

Comment: what is your question exactly ?

Comment: My question got answered by @pumpkinzzz , just a simple css fixed the problem.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's unchecked by default just set a display: none in css to the class and that'it

```
.leaflet-marker-pane{
  display: none;
}
```

or, if it's a dynamic value check on document ready the value and set it, so when refreshing page it will show/hide according to the checkbox value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    check($('#somediv'));
});

$('#somediv').change(function() {
    check($(this));
});

function check(checkbox){
    checkbox.is(":checked") ? $('.leaflet-marker-pane').show() : $('.leaflet-marker-pane').hide();
}
```

check example here: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vhqgtcwu/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you only execute the logic to show/hide the element when the checkbox is changed. You can fix this by triggering the event on load of the DOM. Also note that you can simplify your code using `toggle()`. Try this:

```
$('#somediv').change(function() {
    $('.leaflet-marker-pane').toggle(this.checked)
}).change(); // this triggers the logic on load of the page
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens, 'cause your function only gets fired on change of the checkbox.
a browser refresh is not a change event for the js.

so to achieve your goal, simply add

```
$('.leaflet-marker-pane').hide(1);
```

direct after the onload/domready (whatever you use) call...